# Do you have to restart apache to make re-write rules in the .htaccess take effect?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, restart

I have pushed my .htaccess files to the production severs, but they don't work. Would a restart be the next step, or should I check something else.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

A restart is **not** required for changes to .htaccess.   Something else is wrong.

Make sure your .htaccess includes the statement

> RewriteEngine on

which is required even if it's also present in httpd.conf.  Also check that .htaccess is readable by the httpd process.
Check the error_log - it will tell you of any errors in .htaccess *if* it's being used.
Putting an intentional syntax error in .htaccess is a good check to make sure the file is being used -- you should get a 500 error on any page in the same directory.

Lastly, you can enable a rewrite log using commands like the following in your httpd.conf:

> RewriteLog "logs/rewritelog"
>
> RewriteLogLevel 7

The log file thus generated will give you the gory detail of which rewrite rules matched and how they were handled.

Comment: This is a little out-dated. I ran into a similar issue and wanted to debug my rewrites for a particular use-case. I tried this method, but after a little frustration and digging, i figured out what the problem was. This is for older versions of apache. 

For apache2.4 > replace the RewriteLog & LogLevel above with: `LogLevel alert rewrite:trace7`. 

After **restarting apache**, you should see the traces in the error.log

Hope that helps.

[http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging)

Comment: I use apache 2.4 on Debian, WSL and do not have a httpd config. My htaccess is not recognized.

Answer (score 52):

[No](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/configuring.html#htaccess):

> Apache allows for decentralized management of configuration via special files placed inside the web tree. The special files are usually called `.htaccess`, but any name can be specified in the [AccessFileName](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#accessfilename) directive... Since .htaccess files are read on every request, changes made in these files take immediate effect...

Comment: If you've added the username to 'Require user' in your sites-enabled file I've found empirically that you do need a restart. A graceful one does it.

Answer (score 19):

From the apache documentation:
Most commonly, the problem is that AllowOverride is not set such that your configuration directives are being honored. Make sure that you don't have a AllowOverride None in effect for the file scope in question. A good test for this is to put garbage in your .htaccess file and reload. If a server error is not generated, then you almost certainly have AllowOverride None in effect.

Comment: Dropping link to Apache - AllowOverride:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#AllowOverride

Comment: I add this line "<directory / ></directory>" to my .htaccess to generate an error in the log. It will say "<Directory not allowed here" and I know it's reading my file.

Answer (score 4):

Only if you have *not* added the mod_rewrite module to Apache.

You only need to restart Apache if you change any Apache ".conf" files.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue and it seems PiedPiper post about AllowOverride were most helpful.  Check your httpd.conf file for "AllowOverride" and make sure it is set to All.

Comment: Relevant post: [How to Set AllowOverride all](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18740419/2065702)

Answer (score 2):

In case of .htaccess restart is not required if it is not working probable reasons include.

- [**AllowOverride**](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride) May not be set which user can set inside httpd.conf or might have to contact server admin.
- Check the file name of .htaccess it should be .htaccess not htaccess.txt see [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004633/how-to-manually-create-a-file-with-a-dot-prefix-in-windows-for-example-htacce) for guide how to create one.
- Try to use `Options -Indexes` or `deny all` kind of simple directive to see if it is working or not.
- clear browser cache everytime if having rule for redirects or similar if previous redirect is cached it appears as if things are not working.

Answer (score 0):

What's in your .htaccess? RewriteRules? Check that mod_rewrite is installed and enabled.

Other stuff? Try setting AllowOverride to 'all' on that directory.