# Cannot remove 301 redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I stupidly did a 301 redirect on websiteA.com to websiteB.com. After removing it from the .htaccess file the redirect is still in operation. I tried from outside the local network and it is still redirecting. I have cleared my cache and tried a different browser.

Does anybody have any suggestions?

UPDATE:

If I add a 302 redirect to this .htaccess file the site honours it. When I remove it, the old 301 redirect still happens.

.htaccess file for websiteA.com:

```
# -- concrete5 urls start --

Options -Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
# -- concrete5 urls end --

#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*$
#RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.websiteB\.co\.uk\/" [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Post your full .htaccess here.

Comment: Nothing obviously wrong in this code, can you check matching lines in your access.log?

Comment: Hi :) When I visit the site, one line appears in access log when "tail -f websiteA":  1.1.1.1 - - [24/Feb/2012:13:37:45 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:10.0.2) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0.2"

Comment: It's as if the original 301 permanent redirect is getting cached somewhere. It's not getting cached within my local network because we tried on somebody's mobile using a 3G network.

Comment: .htaccess is not cached, I am suspecting that either have some stray .htaccess somewhere in your DOCUMENT_ROOT or your code is doing this redirection. Will it be possible for you to enable RewriteLog and then check the log entries.

Comment: I found the problem. I had a base url constant in the config PHP for  the site. It had the wrong address in it. Thank you for your assistance anyway.

Answer (score 19):

Try to visit the website with Developers Console open (F12)

Make sure you check "Disable cache" under "Network" tab

[image: bypass 301 redirect]

This will bypass 301 redirect cache on **browser-side**.

Answer (score 17):

The browser caches the 301 Moved **Permanently**, until told otherwise. It is default behavior: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.2.

To fix it in IE9:

1. Open IE9 and press Ctrl+Shift+P for private browsing
2. Navigate to the problem URL
3. Then go back to normal browsing and all should be fine again

Comment: @DaniëlTulp: I think a ctrl-F5 and/or a cache cleaning is enough in firefox.

Answer (score 8):

Just delete the line about the Redirect.

And also everyone who has Google Chrome, do the following steps:

1. Press CTRL + SHIFT + DELETE from your keyboard.
2. Only check -> "Files and images stored in cache"
3. Select in "Elements stored in cache since: Past week"

That will clear all your cache and you'll be fine.

Comment: Do you mean the letters SUPR or is that a key on some keyboards?

Comment: well done!! solved my issue!!!

Answer (score 6):

**The permanent redirect cache is probably in the browser**
and in most browsers it is tricky to remove it.
But first, try using a different browser to see if this is the case.

If the cache is in the browser, cleaning the browser data for that website doesn't work.

To remove the redirection, there is a method for each browser:

- Chrome:
  https://softkube.com/blog/how-make-google-chrome-forget-permanent-http-301-redirect.
- Firefox:
  Open the Developer Tools sidebar (`Tools > Browser Tools > Web Developer Tools`), navigate to the Network tab, toggle Disable HTTP Cache on, and refresh the URL.

**The lesson**
When playing with redirects use [302] first.
After everything was tested ok, change the code to [301]

Comment: R 302 is the safe bet in development environment.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but i spent some time on the Web and my server to find the answer.

If you created an .htaccess file with a permanent redirection, the server will copy this redirection in the following file : "/var/.htaccess".

You have to edit this file to remove the redirection before cleaning the cache of your browser.

It worked on my Debian Jessie.

Comment: I'm not sure whether the absolute path to the file helps the OP and the path you specified is probably not correct (unless your homepage is located in `/var`).

Comment: You are right, the path must be /var in this case, thanks

Answer (score -1):

Try giving Apache a restart

(on Ubuntu servers: `service apache restart` or `/etc/init.d/apache2 restart`)

Comment: The 301 redirection is stored at each of the users browsers, not the server, so it wouldn't really help.

Comment: The redirect may be cached at the browser level but it's the server that throws it. That said, an apache restart should not be required for an .htaccess change so I am definitely wrong http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142559/do-you-have-to-restart-apache-to-make-re-write-rules-in-the-htaccess-take-effec