# Force browsers to forget cached redirects?

Tags: .htaccess, caching, redirect, browser, http-status-code-301

I inherited a domain that previously had a 301 redirect from the root ("/") to "/index.shtml"

I've removed the redirect and a different site on the domain, but people who visited the site in the past will have the redirect behavior cached in their browsers... for a terribly long time, unless they manually clear their caches.

Anyone trying to go to example.com in these browsers will be sent to example.com/index.shtml before they even make any HTTP requests. Right now this is a huge problem because there is no index.shtml, but is there something I can do with headers to tell browsers to "forget about that redirect you just did!"?

Answer (score 16):

The short answer: There is no way to tell the browsers of the users to "forget" the R 301 redirect. 301 means permanent, it can be only undone on action of the user or when the cache expires.

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.2

Similar Q and A on Stackoverflow:
[Apache - how to disable browser caching while debugging htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7743980/apache-how-to-disable-browser-caching-while-debugging-htaccess),
[Cannot remove 301 redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9431164/cannot-remove-301-redirect)

Try to avoid 301 redirects and use 302 (temporarily) instead. Here is an article how to set no cache for 301 redirects (didn't try it):
https://github.com/markkolich/blog/blob/master/content/entries/set-cache-control-and-expires-headers-on-a-redirect-with-mod-rewrite.md

What you could do in your scenario: You could add a header redirect to the file index.shtml, which sends the user to the original file, where he should usually go.

Comment: Redirecting index.shtml back to the root creates a redirect loop in the affected browsers. I made it [302] redirect back to example.com/?home so the URL is at least different, but I'm not sure if that works or not!

Comment: The instruction in the last link to disable cache works by me. Thanks!

Comment: Last link is no longer valid, do you remember the solution for this?

Comment: Even with 302 you have the issue that a browsers keep using a cached redirect although the site is not redirecting anymore. Is there a solution for 302 redirects?

Answer (score 5):

This can be done by a clear data-only cache.
It can remove all,.htaccess redirects changes from the browser.

[image]