# PDF blocked by CORS policy

Tags: angular, pdf, cors

I have issue with CORS policy. I am creating angular app and doing something wrong.

I am running Angular app on localhost:4200 and my api is running at XAMPP localhost. 
I want to load PDF from backend through url. I am using ' apiUrl + "navod/TS02-307_UM.pdf" ', where apiUrl is environment variable: apiUrl: 'http://localhost/'.

While I want to load PDF, I have issue with CORS policy. If I change url to: https://vadimdez.github.io/ng2-pdf-viewer/assets/pdf-test.pdf. Everything working perfectly.

Where should be my mistake? :)

Answer (score 1):

Create a file called ".htaccess" in the directory of your files and add the following to the file.

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://localhost:4200/"
```

or

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

[CORS on apache](https://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html)

Check this flag in your httpd.conf  :

```
AllowOverride All   <--- make sure this is not set to "None"
```

See also: [Do you have to restart apache to make re-write rules in the .htaccess take effect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142559/do-you-have-to-restart-apache-to-make-re-write-rules-in-the-htaccess-take-effec)

Comment: I added ".htaccess" file in the root directory of localhost and it still not working.

Comment: Can you copy it to  navod/ ?  After this do the check:    apachectl -t  (see link) https://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html

Comment: After move, it still not working. Check: Syntax OK

I am using ng2-pdf-viewer for pdf display.

Comment: Do have have an error  log for " I have issue with CORS policy."?

Comment: Access to fetch at 'http://localhost/navod/TS02-307_UM.pdf' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Comment: is there a http:// or a port missing?   Can you see the outgoing url via web developer toolbar? What is the exact outgoing url?

Comment: Thank you. That was a simple and quick fix. I just added the .htaccess file you suggested and instantly our app could access the pdf files in that folder.